# Websphere Encryption getting java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size Error

Tags: java, encryption, websphere

Was trying to encrypt string and pass back to front end as byte array in IBM Websphere. Implementation as per following:

```
        import sc.core.utils.CryptoUtil;

        String msgKey = CryptoUtil.randomString();
        String salt = CryptoUtil.generateSaltKey(); 
        String passphrase = CryptoUtil.getHashSHA512(msgKey); 
        byte[] cipherText = CryptoUtil.encryptWithAlias(nrRecord.getBytes(), passphrase, salt, "CDC");
```

However, I am getting following error message when trying to run the application hosted on webshpere:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
```

WHen I ran as normal Java application, it works fine. Have tried [this solution](https://blog.csdn.net/qinxiaojian2010/article/details/97889467) to set configuration on websphere but to no futile.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Witch IBM JDK version is Websphere using. If it is not one of the latest ones I think you would need to install the unrestricted policy files in the Websphere JDK.

How do I install the unrestricted SDK policy files in WebSphere Application Server from IBM.com?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nz6vJCqvDrc

You can download the unrestricted policy files from the following site:
https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/pickUrxNew.do?source=jcesdk

I hope this helps

Best Regards

Comment: Hi I did updated the policy jars in the websphere folder to still the same